# Oracle HCM Cloud API - Get Workers by HireDate

Tags: oracle, api

How can i retrieve workers who have a particular hire date?

```
`/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/workers?q=HireDate='2011-11-01'&onlyData=true`
```

When i run the above in Postman, i get the following message:

```
URL request parameter q with value HireDate='2011-11-01' is not valid.
```

Any ideas how i can restrict worker data by HireDate or even CreationDate?!

Thanks in advance,
Zaf

Answer (score 0):

I think the `CreationDate` field is not queryable.

However if you can use the `HireDate` then you can use "Like" or between query in the URL.

Example :

```
/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/workers?q=CreationDate like '%2019-05-19%'
/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/workers?q= HireDate between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-01'
```

You can found more details about query parameters of Oracle Rest API in the following link :

[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/human-resources/21c/farws/Query_a_Collection.html)

Otherwise it will be a report that the responsible team will create for you and provide the corresponding API for it.